# Checking for parentheses balance in C

Tags: c, array, homework, stack, balanced-delimiters

A recent assignment asks me to create a program that checks for parentheses balance in a given string. As I can't find any duplicate questions that have code written in C, I decided to post another one.

I tried to make a stack that stores currently opened / unclosed parentheses and checks with each character in array, if it is unbalanced the program flags and depending on the flag boolean prints different value.

Is this the best way? Are there any situations where this program will print incorrect outputs? How can I make it take less time if the input is extremely long?

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int pilepointer=-1,flag=0,i;
    char line[10001],pile[10001];
    gets(line);
    for(i=0;line[i]!=NULL;i++){
        switch(line[i]){
        case '(':
            pilepointer=pilepointer+1;
            pile[pilepointer]='(';
            break;
        case '[':
            pilepointer=pilepointer+1;
            pile[pilepointer]='[';
            break;
        case '{':
            pilepointer=pilepointer+1;
            pile[pilepointer]='{';
            break;
        case ')':
            if(pile[pilepointer]=='('){
                pile[pilepointer]==NULL;
                pilepointer=pilepointer-1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        case ']':
            if(pile[pilepointer]=='['){
                pile[pilepointer]==NULL;
                pilepointer=pilepointer-1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        case '}':
            if(pile[pilepointer]=='{'){
                pile[pilepointer]==NULL;
                pilepointer=pilepointer-1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==1){
        printf("No\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW: `pilepointer` as a name is a) too long (it's C, not Java!), b) semantically wrong (it's not a *real* memory pointer!)

Comment: Is this balancer intended to be run with programming code as the input? Reason for asking is if your balancer is validating code and the code is working with parentheses, you may have syntactically correct, compiling code that is unbalanced in a raw sense.  You'd end up with 'unbalanced' as your answer, which may lead to an incorrect assumption that something is wrong with parenthesis balance in the string. ex) Your code snippet taking out the closing parenthesis case block.

Comment: French course? `pile` should be `stack`.

Comment: @Physics-Compute fortunately it does not need to deal with validating programming code, it would be even harder for me if it did.

Comment: If the question only asks for a match, I would simply count the number of opening/closing paranthesis.

Comment: @Etherealone it also needs to check if it's balanced, so `)))(((` should output `No`.

Comment: @54D Incrementing the counter on '(', decrementing on ')' and checking if it is negative on every operation could work. If the counter ever drops below zero, then it is not balanced. Using an array for storing the open/close pairs and an array for storing counters with indices respective to the open/close pairs can allow using for loop and reduce lines of code and make it easy to extend.

Comment: @Etherealone `([{]})` in your case will give a `Yes` then? This isn't considered as balanced though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Bugs

- The loop header is wrong:

  > ```
  > for(i=0;line[i]!=NULL;i++){
  > ```

  Here, you want to scan until you find a byte with ASCII value 0 (also called an [ASCII NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), and written in C as `'\0'`).  However, you wrote `NULL`, which is supposed to represent a null pointer (a pointer to memory address 0).

  In practice, you might get away with confounding the two, since they are both zero-like in nature, but it is [not semantically correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296843/1157100).
- The result of this comparison is thrown away:

  > ```
  > pile[pilepointer]==NULL;
  > ```

  Did you intend to write `pile[pilepointer] = NULL`?  That wouldn't be quite right either, since you've confused `NULL` and `'\0'` again, as above.  In any case, that statement was unnecessary.
- Stack underflow is possible.  If the input is simply `")"`, for example, you will immediately try to peek at the top of an empty stack (`pile[-1]`), resulting in out-of-bounds memory access.

### Style

- Flag variables suck; flag variables named `flag` are even worse.  At the least, rename it to something meaningful, such as `mismatch_found`.
- When you do

  > ```
  > flag = 1;
  > break;
  > ```

  You are breaking out of the `case`.  However, you need not bother analyzing the rest of the `line`.
- Pushing and popping are clumsily expressed.  I would write:

  ```
  char pile[10001];
  int pile_size = 0;
  ```

  To push:

  ```
  pile[pile_size++] = '(';
  ```

  To pop:

  ```
  if (!pile_size || pile[--pile_size] != '(') {
      // Mismatch detected
  }
  ```
- You can coalesce all of the popping cases, if you push the *expected matching closing delimiter* when you encounter each opening delimiter.

  ```
  for (char *c = line; *c && !mismatch_found; c++) {
      switch(*c) {
      case '(':
          pile[pile_size++] = ')';
          break;
      case '[':
          pile[pile_size++] = ']';
          break;
      case '{':
          pile[pile_size++] = '}';
          break;
      case ')':
      case ']':
      case '}':
          if (!pile_size || pile[--pile_size] != *c) {
              mismatch_found = 1;
          }
          break;
      }
  }
  printf((pile_size == 0 && !mismatch_found) ? "Yes\n" : "No\n");
  ```

Answer (score 13):

The idea is correct, the implementation is not.

- Upon exiting the loop you need to test for `pilepointer == -1`. Otherwise, the strings like `"("` are considered valid.
- A string beginning with the closing parenthesis accesses `pile[-1]`, invoking UB.
- [Never use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).
- Don't put everything in `main`. Separate business logic into a function:

  ```
      int main() {
          ....
          bool valid = check_balance(line);
          print_result(valid);
      }
  ```
- Modern [c](/questions/tagged/c) allows (and recommends) to declare variables as close to use as possible. Preferred idiom is

  ```
      for (int i = 0; ...; ...) {
  ```

Answer (score 11):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't use `gets`

Using `gets` is not good practice because it can lead to buffer overruns.  It has been removed from the C11 standard and marked "obsolete" in POSIX 2008.  Use `fgets` instead, or probably better in this case, `getchar`.  Since the I/O is often buffered anyway, there is unlikely to be a significant difference in performance in most cases.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

This code has a number of inscrutable "magic numbers," that is, unnamed constants such as -1 and 10001.  Generally it's better to avoid that and give such constants meaningful names.  That way, if anything ever needs to be changed, you won't have to go hunting through the code for all instances of "2" and then trying to determine if this *particular* 2 is relevant to the desired change or if it is some other constant that happens to have the same value.

### Use an early bailout

If closing token just read from the stream ever mismatches the desired token, we already know that the answer will be `No`, so rather than having the program read through the rest of the file anyway, the program could simply exit with that message when the first mismatch is detected.

### Use C idioms

Instead of this:

```
pile[pilepointer]==NULL;
pilepointer=pilepointer-1;
```

Write this:

```
pile[pilepointer--] = '\0';
```

And note that `NULL` and the character `'\0'` are not the same thing or necessarily the same value.

### Detect and handle errors

What happens if we put too many things on the stack?  What happens if we try to pop too many off?  Neither potential error case is handled now, but ought to be.

### Break up the code into smaller functions

Rather than having everything in one long function, it would be easier to read and maintain if each discrete step were its own function.  It's not so bad with a relatively short and simple program such as this one, but it helps to get into good habits early.

### Use a data structure

It would probably be worthwhile to create and use an actual stack structure with the appropriate associated functions, such as "push" and "pop".  Here's what the code might look like with such a data structure implemented:

```
bool mismatch(char ch, stack *st) {
    bool mismatched = false;
    switch(ch) {
        case '(':
            stack_push(st, ')');
            break;
        case '[':
            stack_push(st, ']');
            break;
        case '{':
            stack_push(st, '}');
            break;
        case ')':
        case ']':
        case '}':
            mismatched = (ch != stack_pop(st));
        // ignore all other cases
    }
    return mismatched;
}

int main() {
    stack st;
    stack_init(&st);
    bool ok = true;
    for (int ch=getchar(); ch != EOF && ok; ch = getchar()) {
        ok = !mismatch(ch, &st);
    }
    ok = ok && stack_empty(&st);
    stack_destroy(&st);
    printf(ok ? "Yes\n" : "No\n");
    return ok;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the input file can get arbitrarily large, a stack of 10001 elements is not big enough. This is where the code gets ugly, since you need dynamic memory allocation. The best way to deal with this situation is to abstract this whole mess away.

As you said in your description, you are operating on a stack. Your stack needs 3 operations: `push(char)`, `is_empty()` and `pop()`. So imagine you had these functions. Then your code, as improved by @200_success, could look like:

```
static bool is_balanced_stdin(void) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        switch(ch) {
        case '(':
            push(')');
            break;
        case '[':
            push(']');
            break;
        case '{':
            push('}');
            break;
        case ')':
        case ']':
        case '}':
            if (is_empty() || pop() != ch) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return is_empty();
}
```

Note that you don't need to read the input line by line, since line ends don't have anything to do with counting parentheses. Therefore it is better to read character by character. This is what `fgetc` does.

The next thing is that by using the three helper functions, your code becomes very easy to read, since it focuses on the main issue, which is counting the parentheses.

Now all you need is the helper functions, and this is where it gets tricky. Here they are:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    char *data;
    size_t datasize;
} Stack;

Stack stack = { 0, NULL, 0 };

static void push(char ch) {
    if (stack.size >= stack.datasize) {
        size_t newsize = stack.datasize == 0 ? 1024 : 2 * stack.datasize;
        char *newdata = realloc(stack.data, newsize);
        if (newdata == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: not enough memory\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        stack.data = newdata;
        stack.datasize = newsize;
    }
    stack.data[stack.size++] = ch;
}

static char pop() {
    return stack.data[--stack.size];
}

static bool is_empty() {
    return stack.size == 0;
}

static bool is_balanced_stdin(void) {
    // See above
}

int main(void) {
    if (is_balanced_stdin()) {
        printf("Yes\n");
    } else {
        printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

The other nice point is that it is now really simple to say in abstract terms what the program does. You just need to read the code of `main` aloud. That's how programs should be written.

For this programming style, you need to know how to define your own functions, which I demonstrated several times in the above code.

Comment: The idea is sound, but I'd recommend against using a global variable.  Better would be to pass a pointer as my answer shows.